# How to send an email notification to the admin when a student enrolls in course using Enrollment code in Self Enrollment

Tags: php, moodle

I need to send an email notification to admin when a student enroll himself into a course using Self-enrollment course.

In PayPal, there is a setting option called Notify admin this help to send an email notification to a user , but in Self Enrollment I did not find any such option.

Is there some setting to be enabled or I have to write some custom code, If I have to write code to send email notification, then where can I write these code.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job for this and add some time interval to check that user has self enrollment or not. If the user has self enrollment than call another function for send the mail.

```
function checkuser(){ 
$total_time = 0;
$start_time = microtime(true);
while($total_time < 60)//run while less than a minute
 {
   checkFunction(); //DoSomething;
    sleep(20);   //wait amount in seconds
    $total_time =  microtime(true) - $start_time ;
  } 
}

function checkFunction(){
  //check user self enrollment here add into some variable
  // check if it is true than
  if($check == true){
     $to = 'nobody@example.com';
     $subject = 'the subject';
     $message = 'hello';
     $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [local plugin](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins) with an [event observer](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2#Event_observers) that looks for the event '\core\event\course_enrolment_created'.

In the handler function, check to see if $event->other['enrol'] matches 'self' - if not, ignore the event. If it does match, then use the email_to_user() function (or, even better, use the [message API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Message_API)) to send a message to all the relevant users on the course.